# C tokenize and store into array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have a file, I want to read each line, tokenize it by tabs and store into an array. But it turns out that token[0]..token[4] are pointing to addresses of each char that results from strtok(). So token[0]...token[4] change each time I call strtok on the next line of the file. How do I correct this? If I try `char tokens[MAX_SIZE]` instead of `char* tokens[MAX_SIZE]`, an error of conversion occurs because strtok returns char *.

The file is

```
20  34  90  10  77

80  12  37  29  63

45  21  55  18  46
```

My code is:

```
FILE *f;
if ((f = fopen("myinput.txt","r")) == NULL) {
    perror("Failed to open file:");
    return -1;
}
char * line;
size_t len = 0;
char *tokens[MAX_SIZE];
int i = 0;
while (getline(&line, &len, f) !=-1) {

    char* lineWithoutNullByte = strtok(line,"\n");
    tokens[i]=strtok(lineWithoutNullByte,"\t");
    i++;
    int x = 1;
    while (x){

                tokens[i] = strtok(NULL, "\t");
                if (tokens[i] == NULL){
                    x=0;
                }else{
                    i++;
                }


    }
    printf("test: %s %s %s %s %s\n", tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2],tokens[3],tokens[4] );


}
```

The expected output is

```
    test: 20 34 90 10 77
    test: 20 34 90 10 77
    test: 20 34 90 10 77
```

But I am getting:

```
    test: 20 34 90 10 77
    test: 80 12 37 29 63
    test: 45 21 55 18 46
```

To clarify:
This means, if I print the entire `tokens` array, I will be getting

```
45 21 55 18 46
45 21 55 18 46
45 21 55 18 46
```

Comment: Why do you expect the first line repeated three times? What you're getting matches the file, no?

Comment: You see on the 2nd last line, I am printing tokens 0 to 4 only. I was trying to find out what the problem was.

Comment: If I print the whole token array, it will read 45 21 55 18 46 45 21 55 18 46 45 21 55 18 46

Comment: @LearningC Im not sure what you're saying. I want to get an array of size 15, of each of the values in the file.

Comment: `char tokens[MAX_SIZE][3];`...`token=strtok(...);strcpy(tokens[i],token);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using tokens that you get from `strtok` correctly: the tokens that you get come from the buffer returned by `getline`. The first call gives you a new buffer; subsequent calls write into the same buffer, because the line fits into the allocated space.

Since you store pointers into that buffer, the next time a line with new data is placed into the old space, all tokens pointing to that address will "see" the new data. To avoid this problem, you need to copy the tokens right after taking them from `strtok`, for example, by passing them to `strdup`:

```
char *tmp = strtok(NULL, "\t");
if (tmp == NULL) {
    x = 0;
    tokens[i] = NULL;
} else {
    i++;
    tokens[i] = strdup(tmp);
}
```

You would need to `strdup` the first token as well.

Notes: if you take this approach, you would need to `free` the individual tokens once your program is done with them. You also need to free the buffer returned by `getline` at the end of the outer `while` loop:

```
free(line);
```

In addition, `strtok` is non-reentrant, meaning that it cannot be used in concurrent environments, or even to tokenize strings in nested loops. You should use [`strtok_r`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r) instead.

Comment: Dear sir, thanks! Now I understand why. So all it took was to copy the token! I will find out about strtok_r. Thank you very much

Comment: strtok_r is not standard if i'm not mistaken

Comment: @Dabo Correct. Same goes for `getline`, though.

Comment: aahh, did not notice OP is using `getline`, +1

Answer (score 0):

You should use strtok_r instead of strtok. Because strtok just effective in the first time. I don't know reason but I have faced with this problem once time.